# Excel: Stretching a graph on x axis

Tags: excel, charts

In my graph, the x axis are text values. When I make the graph, I cannot stretch it to the whole width. Instead, it takes only less than half of the width.

I usually do this by clicking on "Format Axis", but it doesn't offer that in this case.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: ss]

I'm using Excel for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

When you made the chart, did you select a bunch of empty rows below the range that actually contains data? Looks like twice as much empty data as data with values.

If you select the plot area or chart area, you can see the source data of the chart highlighted in the sheet. You can resize the highlighted range with the mouse to modify the amount of data in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Did they made different types for windows and mac? I'm using windows and scaling is never a problem here.

I can't give you any answer but I can give you a suggestion. Can you check the width of the numbers below the 'Number of public SLA templates' label? Its occupying all the width of your window.